# text keeps flickering after 2 seconds. Coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

So, I have some text that shows up when there is no grenades and currently, it disappears after 2 seconds and then it flickers forever. I just want it to appear for 2 seconds and disappear. Would appreciate some help!

```
if (amountOfGrenades == 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ShowandHideGrenadeText(NOgrenadesText));

        }


IEnumerator ShowandHideGrenadeText(GameObject NOgrenadesText)
    {
        NOgrenadesText.SetActive(true); // Enable the text so it shows
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
        NOgrenadesText.SetActive(false); // Disable the text so it is hidden
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);

    }
```

Comment: Depending on where this is called, isn't `amountOfGrenades` still going to be 0 the next time this is called?

Comment: is there another way to make text disappear after 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not much context provided My guess: you are starting hundreds of **parallel coroutines** because your first snippet is called within Update **every frame** while the condition is met ...

Simply add a second condition like e.g.

```
    if (amountOfGrenades == 0 && !NOgrenadesText.activeSelf)
    {
        StartCoroutine(ShowObjectForTwoSeconds(NOgrenadesText));
    }


// In general be careful with paramter names and existing fields with the same name
// you might confuse them at some point
IEnumerator ShowObjectForTwoSeconds(GameObject obj)
{
    obj.SetActive(true); // Enable the text so it shows
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    obj.SetActive(false); // Disable the text so it is hidden
}
```

Note that a `yield` at the end of a Coroutine makes little sense ;)

---

Or if you really want to wait also 2 secs after turning it back off before being able to.tirn it on again then just introduce an additional flag like e.g.

```
    if (amountOfGrenades == 0 && ! alreadyShowing
    {
        StartCoroutine(ShowObjectForTwoSeconds(NOgrenadesText));
    }

private bool alreadyShowing;

// In general be careful with paramter names and existing fields with the same name
// you might confuse them at some point
IEnumerator ShowObjectForTwoSeconds(GameObject obj)
{
    alreadyShowing = true;

    obj.SetActive(true); // Enable the text so it shows
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    obj.SetActive(false); // Disable the text so it is hidden

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);

    alreadyShowing = false;
}
```

Comment: this just makes it stay on screen forever now.

Comment: This answer has some issues: 1. Why does yield a the end of the Coroutine make little sense? 2. You start the coroutine directly after it stopped making it not do the thing that was asked for. After it ends, it deactivates the NOgrenadesText object just to restart the Coroutine to immediately activate it.

Comment: @MaxPlay because if there is nothing else happening after this last yield .. then it just does nothing .. what is a delay good for if there is nothing it actually delays? The Coroutine itself doesn't delay the code it is starting it. 2) we do not really know what OP asked for except `I just want it to appear for 2 seconds and disappear.` which is exactly what my code does! If it makes you happy I added a second example which allows to show it for 2 seconds and then keeps it hidden for 2 seconds before showing it again ;) But still we don't really know how OPs code and use case looks like

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another possibility to handle this:

Have you thought about using an animation for these kinds of things? And by animation, I mean "not a coroutine."

There are multiple ways to animate this. You could use an [`AnimationCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html) and set the color of the text based on said curve. Or you could create an animation and have an animator for that part of the UI. In the code, you would just trigger a state change in the animator.

Coroutines can be used for the effect you want, but they also come with problems.

This may not be a direct answer to your question, but a solution for a possible [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) that you currently have.